# Android 13 Automotive emulator not work with "No accelerated colorsapce conversion found" warnning

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-automotive, automotive, android-13

I build the Android 13 with sdk_car_x86_64 target, but the emulator does not work. There is one warning log, `[swscaler @ 0x370e000] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to bgra`.

What does that mean? I checked the ffmpeg, kvm, but it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had resolved the issue by starting the emulator with -skin 1200x800 for the target sdk_car_x86_64-userdebug

Comment: nice work, i check the configs in the config.ini and find the key is also the "skin.name". So the reason is lossing the suitable skin.

Answer (score 0):

I had resolved it, the emulator start with black screen becauseof the generated file of config.ini is wrong, just replace it. I think it's a bug of AOSP building.